# How to use attrs attribute on Odoo to combine multiple attributes (invisible, readonly or required) into a single one?

Tags: xml, attributes, field, odoo, odoo-view

In Odoo when you have an xpath you can add "attrs" to a field like required or invisible, when a condition is met. This works fine.

I'm trying to combine those 2. I can't get it to work and can't find anywhere how to do it.

For example this is possible:

```
<field name="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('condition', '=', False)]}"/>
<field name="name2" attrs="{'readonly': [('condition', '=', False)]}"/>
<field name="name3" attrs="{'required': [('condition', '=', False)]}"/>
```

But what I can't get to work is something like:

```
<field name="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('condition1', '=', False)]}, 'required': [('condition2', '=', True)]}"/>
```

I want one field to be invisible when condition 1 is met and (also) required when condition 2 is met.
I've tried different syntaxes but don't know how to do it.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove the `}` symbol. I think that's your mistake

```
<field name="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('condition1', '=', False)], 'required': [('condition2', '=', True)]}"/>
```

Comment: Can I use the syntax as condition1.type1 and condition2.type1 ?
if condition1.type1 has the type1 attribute?

<field name="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('condition1.type1', '=', False)], 'required': [('condition2.type1', '=', True)]}"/>

Comment: @akira I don't think you can use dot notation there. You can always create related fields and use them in the domains